# Problem in implementing file Upload in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I am Implementing a file upload feature to get resume of job applicants in my Reactjs form.
Now whenever I click on Upload everything works fine but while the file is uploading browser throws an error.

Here is my fileUpload.js.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import axios, { CancelToken, isCancel } from "axios";
import { LinearProgressWithLabel } from "./ProgressBar";

const FileUpload = () => {
    const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);
    const cancelFileUpload = useRef(null);

    const uploadFile = ({ target: { files } }) => {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", files[0]);

        const options = {
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;

                let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);

                if (percent < 100) {
                    setUploadPercentage(percent);
                }
            },
            cancelToken: new CancelToken(
                cancel => (cancelFileUpload.current = cancel)
            )
        };

        const BASE_URL = "https://api.quantel.in"
        axios
            .post(
                `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/jobs/resume`,
                data,
                options
            )
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                setUploadPercentage(100);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    setUploadPercentage(0);
                }, 1000);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);

                if (isCancel(err)) {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
                setUploadPercentage(0);
            });
    };

    const cancelUpload = () => {
        if (cancelFileUpload.current)
            cancelFileUpload.current("User has canceled the file upload.");
    };

    return (
        <>
          <p>
              <input
                  type="file"
                  className="form-control-file"
                  onChange={uploadFile}
              />
          </p>
              {uploadPercentage > 0 && (
                  <div className="row mt-3">
                      <div className="col pt-1">
                        <LinearProgressWithLabel value={uploadPercentage} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-auto">
                          <span
                              className="text-primary cursor-pointer"
                              onClick={() => cancelUpload()}
                          >
                              Cancel
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              )}
        </>
    );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

When I click on the browse button the browser throws the following error. And I am confused why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you check for uploadPercentage > 0 change that to this

```
{uploadPercentage > 0 ? (
              <div className="row mt-3">
                  <div className="col pt-1">
                    <LinearProgressWithLabel value={uploadPercentage} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto">
                      <span
                          className="text-primary cursor-pointer"
                          onClick={() => cancelUpload()}
                      >
                          Cancel
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          ) : null }
```

All your code inside { ... } is treated as a function (inside JSX) and in your case when uploadPercentage === 0 it is returning undefined.